# Migrate simple List Array key to another key with an extra attribute in MongoDB

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

Sorry if I'm not getting the terminology right. Here's what I have currently my MongoDB user docs `db.users`:

```
"liked" : [
                "EBMKgrD4DjZxkxvfY",
                "WJzAEF5EKB5aaHWC7",
                "beNdpXhYLnKygD3yd",
                "RHP3hngma9bhXJQ2g",
                "vN7uZ2d6FSfzYJLmm",
                "NaqAsFmMmnhqNbqbG",
                "EqWEY3qkeJYQscuZJ",
                "6wsrFW5pFdnQfoWMs",
                "W4NmGXyha8kpnJ2bD",
                "8x5NWZiwGq5NWDRZX",
                "Qu8CSXveQxdYbyoTa",
                "yLLccTvcnZ3D3phAs",
                "Kk36iXMHwxXNmgufj",
                "dRzdeFAK28aKg3gEX",
                "27etCj4zbrKhFWzGS",
                "Hk2YpqgwRM4QCgsLv",
                "BJwYWumwkc8XhMMYn",
                "5CeN95hYZNK5uzR9o"
        ],
```

And I am trying to migrate them to a new key that also captures the time that a user liked the post

```
"liked_time" : [
                {
                        "postId" : "5CeN95hYZNK5uzR9o",
                        "likedAt" : ISODate("2015-09-23T08:05:51.957Z")
                }
        ],
```

I am wondering if it might be possible to simply do this within the MongoDB Shell with a command that iterates over each user doc and then iterates over the liked array and then updates and $push the new postId and time.

Or would it be better to do this in JavaScript. I am using Meteor.

I almost got it working for individual users. But want to know if I could do all users at once.

`var user = Meteor.users.findOne({username:"atestuser"});`

```
var userLiked = user.liked;

      userLiked.forEach(function(entry) {

        Meteor.users.update({ username: "atestuser" },
          { $push: { liked_times: { postId: entry, likedAt: new Date() }}});

        console.log(entry);
      });
```

Still a bit of a newbie to MongoDB obviously......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is something i made real quick you should run this on the server side just put it into a file e.g. "migrate.js" in root meteor and run the meteor app

```
if (Meteor.isServer) {
    Meteor.startup(function () {
        var users = Meteor.users.find().fetch();

        users.forEach(function (doc) {
            liked.forEach(function (postId) {
                Meteor.users.update(doc._id, { $push: { liked_times: { postId: postId, likedAt: new Date() } } });
            });
        });
        console.log('finished migrating');
    });
}
```

p.s I didn't test it

Comment: Thanks, yes this looks like it will work. I'll give it a go on a copy of my database and let you know.

Comment: Yes, this worked. I only had to make it `doc.liked.forEach` instead of `liked.forEach` and I also wrapped it in a `if (doc.liked)` so that it wouldn't throw an error if the user had zero 'likes'.

Answer (score 1):

If this is a one time migration i would do something like this in a one time js script.

- Get all users
- Iterate over each user
- Get all likes
- Iterate over them, get likedAt

  ```
  var liked_times = _.collect(likes, function (likeId) {
    return {
      'postId' : likeId,
      'likedAt':  // get post liked time from like id. 
    }
  });
  ```
- Insert the above in the collection of choice.

Note:

1. The above example makes use of [lodash](http://npmjs.com/package/lodash)
2. I would rather just save `likedAt` as a timestamp.

Comment: Thanks, yes this is the kind of thing I imagined I'd have to do. I'm not familiar with lodash however, so I might try the other answer first and then come back to this if it doesn't work. Thanks again.